# Automatic Change icon chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I use this code for the icon changes:
Popup.html

```
{{setMyIcon(vm.URL2)}}
```

script

```
 $scope.setMyIcon=function(nameIcon){
       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: nameIcon });
   }
```

But the icon is changed only after clicking on an extension icon (before this was the default). How to do it automatically?

I tried by a timer, but it did not work.

Background js.

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function( alarm ) {
   chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: nameIcon  });
   chrome.alarms.create({'delayInMinutes': 1});
   location.reload();
});

chrome.alarms.create({'delayInMinutes': 1});
```

Now I'm trying to call from the handler function timers basic script.
But how to pass a variable, which is located in the called file (vm.URL2 in weather.js) ? 
Now Icon not change.

```
    chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function( alarm ) {
  // события по будильнику.
  console.log("Got an alarm!");
   alert('great1');
   chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: nameIcon  });
   chrome.alarms.create({'delayInMinutes': 1});
     document.getElementById('$http(request)').src='weather.js'
     chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage('setMyIcon({{vm.URL2}})').src='weather.js'
  });
```

Comment: 1) Currently the alarm is set when the browser starts your extension which happens on browser startup or, in case of event page, when clicking the icon 2) location.reload inside background script is meaningless because it reloads the background page - see the extensions architecture documentation. 3) So the question is, on what condition do you want to change the icon "automatically"?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (and perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: Without a *manifest.json* we can not know, but based on some assumptions: It appears that you were trying to make the change in code associated with a popup, *Popup.html*. This will, of course, do nothing unless the popup exists because the code does not run unless the popup is visible to the user (normally via a user clicking on the browser action, or page action icons). For your other code, a first WAG at it would be: try it without the `location.reload()`. For us to actually Answer your Question, we need a **complte**, but *minimal* [mcve] that duplicates the problem.

Comment: Manifest -http://zalil.su/6665906    I'm trying to do so is to expand the icon (and for good and request) are updated automatically after a certain period of time.

Comment: @Dmitry, content scripts [don't have access to most of chrome.* API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), so you need to do it in the background script.